# Java threading/volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have a thread:

```
class Foo extends Thread
{
    boolean active = true;

    public void run()
    {
        while(active)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    public void end()
    {
        active = false;
    }

    public void hibernate()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            wait();
        }
    }
 }
```

If another thread calls `end()`, will `Foo` immediately see that `active` is now `false`? Specifically, because `active` isn't `volatile`, I'm not sure that it will. I initially created `end()` as a clever way of avoiding volatile, but now I'm unsure that it will actually do what I intend.
Additionally, if another thread calls `hibernate()`, which thread will go to sleep? I'm intending `Foo` to sleep, so if this doesn't do what I intend, an alternative suggestion would be very welcome.

Comment: Any time I see a request for avoiding volatile... I realize someone/somehow/somewhere failed (BIG time) to explain that volatile reads are cheap on virtually all the hardware. Volatiles just ensure ordering semantics, and volatile read is just an ordered read that technically may prevent some optimizations by the CPU (i.e. unordered loads) but you should never care about. Volatile writes are more expensive since they require all writes (cache lines) to be flushed but volatile writes are usually rare too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If another thread calls end(), will Foo immediately see that active is now false?

No it won't.  Or at least, it won't see it all of the time.

If you want `run` to always see the new value immediately, there has to be a "comes after" relationship between the thread assigning to the variable and the thread reading it.  This can be achieved:

- by declaring `active` volatile,
- by putting `synchronized` blocks around the statements that read and write the variable,
- by making the variable an "atomic" type; e.g. `AtomicBoolean`, or
- by using some other appropriate concurrency class; see the `java.util.concurrent.*` packages.

> ... a clever way of avoiding volatile ...

Declaring the variable to be volatile is one way of ensuring proper synchronization.  It is a fact that proper synchronization imposes a performance overhead.  However, proper synchronization is essential for your application to work reliably, and it is NOT "clever" to avoid it.

(Without proper synchronization, your program will probably still work most of the time, and it might even always work on some machines.  However, occasionally it won't work, and the actual behavior is likely to depend on what machine you run the program on, what the machine load is, and other things.)

> Additionally, if another thread calls hibernate(), which thread will go to sleep?

The thread that makes the call will go to sleep.  And it won't wake up unless some other thread does a `notify` or `notifyAll` on the same Foo object.

If you simply want the application to go to sleep and wake up a bit later, use `Thread.sleep`.  But beware that using `sleep` in the wrong way can make your application slow and unresponsive.

Answer (score 6):

Your suspicion is correct: because `active` isn't `volatile`, there is no guarantee that `run()` will ever see the change made on another thread.

Generally speaking, “clever” ways of avoiding `volatile` are almost always a bad idea. In fact, even `volatile` is something you should prefer not to resort to. Most of the time it's safer to stick to locks, monitors, or higher-level synchronization mechanisms.

For your second question, the thread that will go to sleep is the one that called `hibernate()`. That thread will sleep until it is interrupted, it experiences a spurious wakeup, or some other thread calls `notify()`/`notifyAll()` on the `Foo` instance's monitor. It is usually a mistake to call `Object#wait()` without surrounding it with a loop that checks the condition being waited for.

<strike>You also seem to be confused about the idea of a `Foo` instance “going to sleep”. A `Foo` instance isn't a `Thread` (or even a `Runnable`), and doesn't create its own thread, so the idea of it going to sleep doesn't make a lot of sense. What you are probably trying to achieve is putting the thread calling `Foo#run()` to sleep.</strike>

Comment: Re: Foo vs an instance of Foo, I do know the difference. I just didn't feel like writing Foo bar = new Foo(); bar.start(); and ask all my questions about bar.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the distinction between the `Foo` class and an instance of it; I was referring to the fact that your `Foo` class doesn't extend `Thread` and therefore isn't itself a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question of avoiding volatile , you should try using Thread interruption to signal a running thread to stop.

Use [interrupt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt) instance method from another thread to interrupt running thread.

Use [isInterrupted()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) method in your running thread to check for interruption.

```
while(!this.isInterrupted()){
   //do your work here.
}
```

Not sure why you want to extend Thread class. If you implements Runnable in that case you should use [interrupted](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted) in your run method to check for interruption . Please read javadocs to know about some caveats of this method.